# zero-length variable name for the line ```{r} or ````

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I work in rmarkdown I'm often confronted with the following issue:
The code inside the chunk does work but I can't knit the document because it tells me that there is an error on the line with the {r} or ```

````
```{r}
model1 <- lm(Density~Hardness)
coef(model1)
``` 

Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
````

Comment: You should make a complete document that has this problem and post it here -- we need something reproducible to see what's going wrong.  It doesn't need to be a big document; minimal is best.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rmarkdown error "attempt to use zero-length variable name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171362/rmarkdown-error-attempt-to-use-zero-length-variable-name)

Comment: Generally, RMD indicates errors for anything within a chunk referencing the first line of that chunk. In other words, your mistake can be anywhere inside the chunk.