# R Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: r, r-markdown, data-visualization, bokeh, dashboard

I am using the R programming language. I am following a tutorial here on making an interactive dashboard with the famous iris data set : https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/jjallaire/htmlwidgets-rbokeh-iris/htmlwidgets-rbokeh-iris.html

I copy and pasted the source code (after installing the necessary libraries):

````
---
title: "rbokeh iris dataset"
author: "Ryan Hafen"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(rbokeh)
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=600}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Species

```{r}
figure(width = NULL, height = NULL) %>%
  ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris, color = Species)
# figure() %>%
#   ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris,
#     color = Species, glyph = Species)
```


Column {data-width=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Species (Quantile)

```{r}
figure(width = NULL, height = NULL, legend_location = "top_left") %>%
  ly_quantile(Sepal.Length, group = Species, data = iris)
```

### Petal Width

```{r}
figure(width = NULL, height = NULL) %>%
  ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris,
    color = Petal.Width)
```
````

And this produced many errors:

````
> Column {data-width=600}
Error: unexpected '{' in "Column {"
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
+     
+     ### Species
+     
+     ```{r}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> figure(width = NULL, height = NULL) %>%
+     ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris, color = Species)
> # figure() %>%
> #   ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris,
> #     color = Species, glyph = Species)
> ```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> 
> 
> Column {data-width=400}
Error: unexpected '{' in "Column {"
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
+     
+     ### Species (Quantile)
+     
+     ```{r}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> figure(width = NULL, height = NULL, legend_location = "top_left") %>%
+     ly_quantile(Sepal.Length, group = Species, data = iris)
> ```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> 
> ### Petal Width
> 
> ```{r}
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
> figure(width = NULL, height = NULL) %>%
+     ly_points(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = iris,
+               color = Petal.Width)
> ```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
````

This produces all the plots individually, e.g :

[image]

But it does not produce an "interactive dashboard" as produced from the website. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing spaces from author and title?

Comment: I just tried that right now. It didn't work. I also tried removing them all together and it still didnt work. Did you mean the spaces after the ":" ? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171362/rmarkdown-error-attempt-to-use-zero-length-variable-name

Comment: Thank you, I saw this post and I am trying to understand the many answers provided here and how they apply to my question. So far, I am still confused...

Comment: @ronak shah: if you have time, can you please show me how i could fix this code? Thank you

Comment: Copying your code as it is in an Rmd flexdashboard file and knitting it with `Knit to flexdashboard` works for me without any error.

Comment: @RonakShah: I entered this line of code to create a new "Rmd flexdashboard file" : rmarkdown::draft("dashboard.Rmd", template = "flex_dashboard", package = "flexdashboard") . I copy and pasted the original code and clicked "save". I then tried to preview the file by entering this code : rmarkdown::run(input = "dashboard.Rmd", output_format = "html_document") ... but I got an error: Error in rmarkdown::run(input = "dashboard.Rmd", output_format = "html_document") : 
  unused arguments (input = "dashboard.Rmd", output_format = "html_document") ... do you know what I am doing wrong? thank you

Comment: Is it possible to save the final product as a "html" file?

Comment: @RonakShah : I continued to work on this question and posted a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621723/r-converting-rmarkdown-to-html-files can you please take a look at if you have time? thank you

Comment: I just encountered this error. It was caused by trying to do various dplyr manipulations when one of the columns in the table actually had an empty string "" for a column name. I located the cause of this upstream and it fixed the problem.  If you can check any intermediate steps, I'd recommend inpsecting the table you're trying to plot, and ensure that no spurious columns were added, or any names removed.