# R Error: "attempt to use zero-length variable name" when using "Preview on save"

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, rnotebook

It seems there is a problem on "Preview on Save" option in RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554.

The code below is saved as "tmp1.Rmd". I can run chunks, and I CAN use Preview button (it works). But I can NOT save with "Preview on Save" option set.
When I change YAML Header output from `output: html_notebook` to `output: html_document` the error stops (I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171362/rmarkdown-error-attempt-to-use-zero-length-variable-name)).
Is this an RStudio bug?
The code:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

# VE

```{r}
x=3  
```  

end
````

Comment: @LuckyOwl but the "Preview" works fine... And when Rstudio creates a new RMarkdown doc, it uses `output: html_notebook`